# rotate around object smoothly in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I have two images moving around a DOM element. But their rotation is wrong and the movement is not smooth.

My fiddle

```css
#mainPage {
  width: 400px;
  height: 165px;
  margin: 10% auto;
}

#mainPage>p {
  text-align: center;
}

.bicycle {
  width: 48px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}

#bicycleOriginal {
  animation: moveBicycleOriginal 20s infinite;
}

#bicycleFlipped {
  animation: moveBicycleFlipped 20s infinite;
}

#mainTxt {
  letter-spacing: 7px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

@keyframes moveBicycleOriginal {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  1% {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(350px, 0);
  }
  26% {
    transform: translate(350px, 0) rotate(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(350px, 150px);
  }
  51% {
    transform: translate(350px, 150px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  76% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px) rotate(270deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes moveBicycleFlipped {
  from {
    transform: translate(350px, 0);
  }
  1% {
    transform: translate(350px, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  26% {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0, -150px);
  }
  51% {
    transform: translate(0, -150px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(350px, -150px);
  }
  76% {
    transform: translate(350px, -150px) rotate(270deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(350px, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mainPage">
  <div class="bicycle" id="bicycleOriginal"></div>

  <p class="txt" id="mainTxt">DRAHTESEL</p>

  <div class="bicycle" id="bicycleFlipped"></div>
</div>
```

So what I want is something like this

[image: Rotation]

After passing the first keyframe the boxes get into a wrong rotation. Also they don't move smoothly, the get faster in the middle and slower when reaching the end.

Could someone help me with the keyframes?

Comment: this looks very smooth to me. Chrome on Arch on an i3 intel from 2014. So not even the latest hardware involved.

Comment: but the rotation is wrong. you will see the wrong part after the first keyframe

Comment: As for the slowing down in the middle, you will need to change the easing to linear: [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-timing-function.asp)

Answer (score 7):

You need to always keep the rotate defined within the transform because each transform will override the previous one and removing the rotation means `rotate(0)`.

And to make the animation more accurate, the last state should be similar to the first state to avoid the jump when restarting the animation. So you should go to `360deg` of rotation which is equivalent to `0deg`. *(like you did with the translation where you come back to the initial value)*.

Then you may adjust the [`animation-timing-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) to control the animation progress if needed.

```css
#mainPage {
  width: 400px;
  height: 165px;
  margin: 10% auto;
}

#mainPage>p {
  text-align: center;
}

.bicycle {
  width: 48px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}

#bicycleOriginal {
  animation: moveBicycleOriginal 20s infinite;
}

#bicycleFlipped {
  animation: moveBicycleFlipped 20s infinite;
}

#mainTxt {
  letter-spacing: 7px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

@keyframes moveBicycleOriginal {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(350px, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  26% {
    transform: translate(350px, 0) rotate(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(350px, 150px) rotate(90deg);
  }
  51% {
    transform: translate(350px, 150px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  76% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px) rotate(270deg);
  }
  98% {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(270deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes moveBicycleFlipped {
  from {
    transform: translate(350px, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg);
  }
  26% {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0, -150px) rotate(90deg);
  }
  51% {
    transform: translate(0, -150px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(350px, -150px) rotate(180deg);
  }
  76% {
    transform: translate(350px, -150px) rotate(270deg);
  }
  97% {
    transform: translate(350px, 0) rotate(270deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(350px, 0) rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mainPage">
  <div class="bicycle" id="bicycleOriginal"></div>

  <p class="txt" id="mainTxt">DRAHTESEL</p>

  <div class="bicycle" id="bicycleFlipped"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer !  But I could resist to post another one, mainly to change the way the object rotates around the corners

Comment: @vals i like it +1 :) it is more likely an animation of cars unlike mine where it's more a soldier movement :p

Answer (score 2):

The speed slowing/speeding is because of the animationTiming (default ease), that should be 'linear'.

The reason the animation is incorrect, it because you unset the rotation. This might come unexpected, you control transformation with css `transform`. You also control rotation with `transform`.

```
#example{
    transform: rotate(10deg)
}
#example.changed{
    transform: translateX(100px);
}
```

In this snippet, when you add the class `changed` you redefine transform, telling it to forget `rotate` and set `translateX`. In this example, to keep them both:

```
#example.changed{
    transform: rotate(10deg) translateX(100px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have taken the answer from Temani Afif, and changed it a little bit.

I set an aditional transform, applied after the rotation. This makes the turn be *smooth* in the sense that the object rotates following a path and not in the same place

I have set the timing to linear, as suggested by Martijn

I have simplified it to use a single keyframes rule, setting a delay on the flipped div.

And made longer the time slice for the long sides and shoprter the other, so that the perceived speed is more constant

The result:

```css
#mainPage {
  width: 400px;
  height: 165px;
  margin: 10% auto;
}

#mainPage>p {
  text-align: center;
}

.bicycle {
  width: 48px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
}

#bicycleOriginal {
  animation: moveBicycleOriginal 20s infinite linear;
}

#bicycleFlipped {
  position: relative;
  top: -120px;
  animation: moveBicycleOriginal 20s -10s infinite linear;
}

#mainTxt {
  letter-spacing: 7px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

@keyframes moveBicycleOriginal {
  from {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(0deg) translate(0, -50px);
  }
  26% {
    transform: translate(350px, 0) rotate(0deg) translate(0, -50px);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translate(350px, 0) rotate(90deg)  translate(0, -50px);
  }
  46% {
    transform: translate(350px, 150px) rotate(90deg) translate(0, -50px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(350px, 150px) rotate(180deg)  translate(0, -50px);
  }
  76% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px) rotate(180deg)  translate(0, -50px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px) rotate(270deg)  translate(0, -50px);
  }
  96% {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(270deg)  translate(0, -50px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(0, 0) rotate(360deg)  translate(0, -50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mainPage">
  <div class="bicycle" id="bicycleOriginal"></div>

  <p class="txt" id="mainTxt">DRAHTESEL</p>

  <div class="bicycle" id="bicycleFlipped"></div>
</div>
```